# How to attach functions to Qwidget which are not in global scope in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a vertical menu in QT ( I'm a newbie , so bear with me ).
I am trying to attach addFunction function from sidebar.h to qwidget. Any help will be appreciated

**Error**

```
D:\Projects\mainwindow.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to 'QWidget::addAction(QIcon, QString)'
       ui->widget->addAction(QIcon(QString(":/icons/icon%1").arg(i)) , QString("Action %1").arg(i));
                                                                                                  ^
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "sidebar.h"
#

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    for(int i= 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
      ui->widget->SideBar::addAction(QIcon(QString(":/icons/icon%1").arg(i)) , QString("Action %1").arg(i));
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**sidebar.cpp**

```
QAction *SideBar::addAction(const QString &text, const QIcon &icon)
{
    QAction *action = new QAction(icon, text, this);
    action->setCheckable(true);
    mActions.push_back(action);
    update();
    return action;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the error message I see that `QWidget::addAction(QIcon, QString)` is tried to be called. According to the Qt docs such a method does not extist; only `QWidget::addAction(QAction *)`. Try please the following:

`ui->widget->SideBar::addAction( new QAction( QIcon(QString(":/icons/icon%1").arg(i)) , QString("Action %1").arg(i)) );`

Comment: I’m getting error that sidebar is not a base of qwidget

Comment: So, `ui->widget` is `QWidget*`, not `Sidebar*`. You have to cast it: `dynamic_cast<SideBar*>(ui->widget)->addAction(...)`

Comment: Or, alternatively, use "promote to" in Qt Designer: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Answer (score 0):

You have text and icon parameters in reversed order:

```
ui->widget->SideBar::addAction(QIcon(...) , QString(...).arg(i));
```

and

```
QAction* SideBar::addAction(const QString &text, const QIcon &icon)
```

Comment: I did switch it back but I’m still getting the error that Sidebar is not base of qwidget